# Rust Simple Stats Program

Tags: rust

I am brand new to Rust and want to know if there are any convention violations in my code and ways how I can make it more readable:

```rust
use std::io;

fn main() {
    let mut vec: Vec<i32> = Vec::new();
    loop {
        println!("Enter any number, 0 to terminate");
        let mut num = String::new();
        io::stdin()
            .read_line(&mut num);
        if num.trim().parse::<i32>().unwrap() == 0 {break;}
        vec.push(num.trim().parse::<i32>().unwrap());
    }
    let sum: i32 = vec.iter().sum();
    println!("Sum: {}", sum);
    println!("Min: {}", vec.iter().min().unwrap());
    println!("Max: {}", vec.iter().max().unwrap());
    println!("Mean: {}", sum as f32 / vec.len() as f32);
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```rust
io::stdin().read_line(&mut num);
```

Here you are ignoring the `Result` from `read_line`; you should have seen a compiler warning about this. Add `.unwrap()` or `.expect()` to check the error and panic if there is a problem reading:

```rust
io::stdin().read_line(&mut num).expect("Read error");
```

(Below I'll be talking about *handling* errors instead of panicking. This case is different because an IO error during reading *shouldn't occur in normal usage* and there isn't really any way to recover from it.)

---

```rust
        if num.trim().parse::<i32>().unwrap() == 0 {break;}
        vec.push(num.trim().parse::<i32>().unwrap());
```

In these two lines you are parsing the number twice. Put the parse result in a variable instead.

```rust
        let num = num.trim().parse::<i32>().unwrap();
        if num == 0 {break;}
        vec.push(num);
```

---

If the user makes a typo and enters something that does not parse as `i32` (e.g. a letter) then the program will panic since you are `.unwrap()`ing the parse result. It probably makes sense to tell the user and let them reenter instead. We can combine that with the handling of `0` inputs:

```rust
        match num.trim().parse::<i32>() {
            Err(_) => {
                println!("{:?} wasn't an integer. Try again.", num);
            }
            Ok(0) => {
                break;
            }
            Ok(x) => {
                vec.push(x);
            }
        }
```

---

Finally, you used `.unwrap()` for the min and max, which means that it will panic if the user doesn't enter any numbers. It's generally better for a program to not panic on any input. We can eliminate the `unwrap` from a single print like this:

```rust
    if let Some(min) = vec.iter().min() {
        println!("Min: {}", min);
    }
```

But, since three of the four outputs don't make sense for zero items, I think it makes more sense to put them inside a single condition, even if that means keeping the unwraps:

```rust
    println!("Sum: {}", sum);
    if !vec.is_empty() {
        println!("Min: {}", vec.iter().min().unwrap());
        println!("Max: {}", vec.iter().max().unwrap());
        println!("Mean: {}", sum as f32 / vec.len() as f32);
    }
```

---

One more thing. If the input to the program reaches end-of-file without containing 0, it will loop infinitely, reading no characters and producing error messages. (Well, your initial version didn't, because it panicked on a parse error instead). The right thing to do is to check whether `read_line` met end of file; this is reported in the return value but also detectable by the fact that `num` will be the empty string (without any newline).

```rust
        io::stdin().read_line(&mut num).unwrap();
        if num == "" {
            break;
        }
```

---

Putting together all my suggested changes:

```rust
use std::io;

fn main() {
    let mut vec: Vec<i32> = Vec::new();
    loop {
        println!("Enter any number, 0 to terminate");
        let mut num = String::new();
        io::stdin().read_line(&mut num).unwrap();
        if num == "" {
            break;
        }
        match num.trim().parse::<i32>() {
            Err(_) => {
                println!("{:?} wasn't an integer. Try again.", num);
            }
            Ok(0) => {
                break;
            }
            Ok(x) => {
                vec.push(x);
            }
        }
    }
    let sum: i32 = vec.iter().sum();
    println!("Sum: {}", sum);
    if !vec.is_empty() {
        println!("Min: {}", vec.iter().min().unwrap());
        println!("Max: {}", vec.iter().max().unwrap());
        println!("Mean: {}", sum as f32 / vec.len() as f32);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. If you really intended the app to be used, you would probably want to use `StructOpt` to give help, etc.
2. There are several places where the program looks like it would crash if you just immediately gave it a 0 without any other values: the `.unwrap()`s and the division at the end.  You would probably want to check for that up front.
3. Rather than doing `unwrap()`s like that you could use the `anyhow` crate and make `main` return a `Result<()>`.  Then your `.unwrap()`s could just be `?`s.
4. You can change the way input is provided to make the program much more flexible AND make the code easier to read.  Just read lines from stdin until EOF, `flat_map` them to the numbers they contain, and collect the results as a `Vec` -- all in one line (something like `stdin.lock().lines().flat_map(...).collect())`.
5. You could make the program able to handle arbitrarily large data sets by NOT collecting the results in a `Vec`, but rather `fold()`ing to get the sum, min, max, and count, and then using those to produce the output at the end.

Update: I decided to go ahead and implement 2/4/5, to see what it would look like; [here it is in the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=eb1ce294561d5703150d7169f0ba7b53).  And actually, that `unwrap()` on the parse should really be an `expect`.